# capturing event of a photo click in code: iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, alassetslibrary, alasset

I want to create an environment similar to the photo streaming in iCloud.
When my app is in background, can I get the events of user clicking photos through the Camera app of iPhone?
A sample code would be of great help.

Comment: You can' access the Camera App activity while your app being into background state.

Comment: Thanks Neon. Any option - round about way to do this?

Comment: In Short What you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is No.

The sandbox principle means that you cannot access another apps environment and a another app cannot access yours.

Ways for your app to access the Camera are via the `AVCaptureSession` classes or the `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: There is a third party app "OneMediaHub" that is doing photo streaming. I think it's checking if there are new photos available when the app comes back in foreground. How can this be implemented?

Comment: At a guess they are analyzing the assets library contents and looking for changes.